# Add React to a static Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How to add React to a static website build with Gatsby?

I'm Gatsby and React beginner and I (still) do not fully understand the relevant documentation.

As a starter to go further, I would like to integrate the simple example at https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html to a static Gatsby site, like this starter page `gatsby new hello-world https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world`.

Motivation: It's a requirement of the site, I try to port. Two pages are mainly "powered" by two React apps/components. I have access to the source code and it's possible to do small changes. These React apps/components perform client side logic including access to local storage and XHR/fetch.

One option would be to modify and build the React app aside and transfer it manually to the Gatsby site. I did not test this, but probably something like a copy to `/static/js/my-client-side-react-app.js` would do the job.

I believe there is a smarter Gatsby-like way to achieve this. It would be helpful, if someone can point me to the right direction. Perhaps a link to a very simple Hello World example. I'm willing to do my homework, but just don't get it at the moment and don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Gatsby is already utilizing React.  No need to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gatsby starter you linked to already contains React:

[index.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world/blob/master/src/pages/index.js)

```
import React from "react"

export default function Home() {
  return <div>Hello world!</div>
}
```

Don't bother with the examples from the React docs. These are meant to describe how you add React to a classic website with only HTML + CSS. This is not necessary for Gatsby because the Gatsby framework does this for you automatically.

In short: How to add React to a static Gatsby site?

You don't need to because Gatsby ships with React.

Comment: Thanks EliteRaceElephant and @Mark. Simple answer silly question but helped a lot. After rethinking React/Gatsby (both new to me), it's very clear now.